# Заменить цифры на символ * в string

Tags: c#, строки

Дана строка с символами,например,"aaaa456bbb", и надо заменить все цифры на символ * не используя встроенные функции string.

Comment: Это неразрешимая задача. В C# строки - неизменяемы, получить новую строку из старой можно (строго говоря) только используя, прямо или косвенно, встроенные функции string - (методы, или минимум геттеры свойств - это тоже функции). Так что без встроенный функций string вы ничего со строкой не сделаете.

Comment: @PashaPash Наверное предполагается, что на вход функции подаётся не `string`, а `char[]`?

Answer (score 4):

```
string replaced = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace("aaaa456bbb", @"\d", "*")
```

Answer (score 2):

Используя Linq:

```
var res = new string(s.Select(c => char.IsDigit(c) ? '*' : c).ToArray());
```

Если конструктор string тоже не запрещен, конечно.

Используя StringBuilder:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var c in s)
    sb.Append(char.IsDigit(c) ? '*' : c);
var res = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял условие, то так :

```
    string s="1212edwe3";
    string s2=""; //конечный результат будет тут
    char[] mass = new char[]{'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0'};

     foreach (var m in s){
        var b=false;

            for (int k=0; k<mass.Count(); k++)
                if (mass[k]==m)
                b=true;


         if(b)
                s2 +="*";
                else
                s2 +=m;

    }
    Console.Write(s2);
```

Comment: раз уж используете функцию-геттер s.Length - гораздо проще было бы использовать функцию Replace - и то и то нарушает правила :)

Comment: @PashaPash а, точн )) я даж забыл про Length )) как вариант : заменить фор на форич ))

Answer (score 0):

Я так думаю что можно написать так:

```
string input = "te8tw1thn0m69r3"; // входные данные
sring answer = "";                // конечный результат
foreach (var chr in input)
{
    (Convert.ToInt16(chr)>=0&&Convert.ToInt16(chr)<=9)answer+="*":answer+=chr;  // проверка на число
}
Console.Write(answer);            // вывод результата
```